# How to insert text on the line after the last occurence of a search string?

Tags: replace, insert, find

I've been trying to rack my brain for a few hours on this one.

I've trying to write a script that will insert an extra include file and comment after the last occurence of the existing include file in a set of source *.cpp files. The source files are in a recursive set of directories, so I suppose my scrupt will have to begin with a find.

For instance, before:

```
#include <a>
#include <b>
#include <c>
// source code...
```

After:

```
#include <a>
#include <b>
#include <c>
// This is the extra include file
#include <d>
// source code...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in python, I have made an example script below:

```
import os

def find_last_include(file_name):
    """ Returns last line with an include statement at the start """
    last_include_line = 0
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f):
            if line.strip().startswith("#include"):
                last_include_line = max(i, last_include_line)
    return last_include_line



def insert_line(file_name, last_include_line_no, new_line):
    """ New line should end with \n"""
    try:
        with open(file_name,"r+") as f:
            print "Opening: {0}".format(file_name)
            # File is all the lines in the file as a list
            file = f.readlines()
            # last include line is the line we are going to replace the last inculde
            # with the last include + the new line we want
            last_include_line = file[last_include_line_no] + new_line
            file[last_include_line_no] = last_include_line
            print "Inserting: '{0}' On line: {1}".format(new_line.strip(), last_include_line_no)
            f.seek(0)  # Seek back to the start of the file
            for line in file:
                f.write(line)  # Write the lines with changes to the file
    except IOError as e:
        print e
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c_files = find_all(".c","Y:\\Python Stuff")
    line =  "#include <c>\n"
    for c_file in c_files:
        insert_line(c_file, find_last_include(c_file), line)
    print "Finished Inserting lines"
```

This prints:

```
SEARCHING FOR FILES..
FOUND FILE: Y:\Python Stuff\prog.c
Finished finding
Opening: Y:\Python Stuff\prog.c
Inserting: #include <c> On line: 34
Finished Inserting lines
```

What this is doing is finding all the ".c" files starting from a given folder, then finds what line the last include is on and adds the line to that line and rewrites the file. Works like a charm. Any comments for improvement would be appreciated though.

Comment: I think the question implies that he does not know what what <c> is and simply wants to find the last #include line in the file. He'll need to read the entire file then go back and add the new lines once he knows where the last include actually is.

Comment: oo could do that will have to have a rethink of my strat

Comment: @noelkd: Yes, #include <c> indicates inclusion of any file, either inside angle brackets or quotes. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @noelkd: This is what I was looking for. Many thanks, sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague. So i'll break up what you need to do.

1. Find where the end of the includes are (regular expression, hand written function).
2. Split the original text into two parts.
3. head + your include + tail = new text.
4. write the new text into a temp file.
5. delete old file.
6. rename temp file to old file name.

You can use C++ for this, and boost(as well as c++11) has all the abstractions you need.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure you've discovered by now the hard part of this problem is "after the last occurrence of."  It reminds me of my Grandpa who live 87 years in the same town and would occasionally give directions like "we're just a block past the last gas station on Main St."  Unless you knew Main St. well enough to know that the last Station was the 76 you could end up in the next town wondering if there was still another gas station coming.

So what is the solution?  Theoretically the last occurrence of an include could be the last line of the file. You therefore need to take a first pass through and read the entire file into memory keeping track of where that last include line happened. Then take a second pass writing each line out until you hit the that last occurrence, write your additional include, then the rest of the lines.

There are, I believe, ways to do this in a streaming manor, but they still will require two passes through your data.  On the other hand, this clearly a source code file which means it if rather small and will easily fit in memory.

However, knowing something about a typical source code patterns, you may be able to get away with looking for the first occurrence of a line that is *not* `include ...` and inserting your new include just before it.

Comment: The corner case you are describing I wouldn't even cater for. It implies no coding conventions are in place whatsoever.